# TypeError: reservationService.getPendingReservations is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

> angular.js:13708 TypeError: reservationService.getPendingReservations
>   is not a function

When I load  page the first time I get this error, but giving F5 the page, load smoothly.

Below I show my code. Which I can not find the error. I've been checking some forums which indicate that it may be related to dependency injection but still can not find the error. I did a test and I realized that when the page loads the first time, the factory is uninitialized, if this is not related to this.

**homeController.js**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$route', '$location', 'authService', 'reservationService', 'localStorageService',
    function ($scope, $route, $location, authService, reservationService, localStorageService) {


    $scope.showNotifications = function () {
        updateNotifications();
        $("#notificationContainer").fadeToggle(600);
        //hideCountNotifications();
    }


function updateNotifications() {

        reservationService.getPendingReservations(authData.id_place).then(function (results) {
            if (results.status != 200) {
                $scope.message = "Upps! Lo siento, creo que tenemos un problema al cargar las notificaciones.";
                console.log(results);
            }
            else {
                $scope.notifications = results.data;
                $scope.cantPendingReservations = results.data.length;

                //// La primera vez que carga la pagina se llamada el metodo para que recargue la grilla
                //reloadGrid();
            }
            //$scope.$emit('UNLOAD')
            //$("#tableScheduler").show();

        }, function (error) {
            if (error.status == 401) { authService.logOut(); $location.path('/login'); }
        });
    }


}]);
```

**reservationService.js**

```
'use strict';
app.factory('reservationService', ['$http', '$q', 'localStorageService', 'servicesConnect', function ($http, $q, localStorageService, servicesConnect) {

    var serviceBase = servicesConnect.apiFutbolPlay;
    var reservationService = {};

    var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
    if (authData) {
        var _ListPitch = function (id_place) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/pitches/single/' + id_place).then(function (results) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            }, function errorCallback(err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        var _ListPendingReservations = function (id_place) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/reservations/customer/myreservations/' + id_place, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }).then(function (results) {
                deferred.resolve(results);
            }, function errorCallback(err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }


        reservationService.getPendingReservations = _ListPendingReservations;
    }

    return reservationService;

}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="FutPlayApp">
<head>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="images/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="homeController">
        <div data-ng-view="">


        </div>        

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load Angular -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/datetimepicker.templates.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/dateTimeInput.js"></script>
    <!--Autocompletado-->
    <script src="scripts/angucomplete-alt.js"></script>
    <!-- Load app main script -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <!-- Notificaciones de reservas de usuario -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/pnotify.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load services -->
    <script src="app/services/authInterceptorService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/authService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/reservationService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/schedulerService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/profileService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/changepasswordService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/reservationmultipleService.js"></script>

    <!-- Load controllers -->
    <script src="app/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/reservationController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/schedulerController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/profileController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/changepasswordController.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/reservationmultipleController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that `reservationService.getPendingReservations` is initialised only if `'authorizationData'` exists in local storage. If it doesn't then `getPendingReservations` is never set to anything.

My guess is that elsewhere in your code, `authorizationData` is stored in local storage, so that when you refresh the page the function becomes available.

To solve this problem, you will need to restructure your reservation service to deal with situations where authorisation has not happened, or perform checks before you attempt to use `getPendingReservations`.

Comment: I want to thank your answer but I do not have the minimum 15 points to do so. But I run your solution. Greetings from Colombia.